# Конвертация строк, Python

Tags: python, unicode

Как из обычной строки сделать юникод строку? Проблема в том, что выпадает такое сообщение

> UnicodeEncodeError:
> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5:
> ordinal not in range(128)

Как я понял, надо сделать из обычной строки строку юникода. Может есть другие решения?

Comment: @pyVyp Для сообщений об ошибках удобно использовать цитатное форматирование.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать стандартные средства

```
someString = "string"
someString.encode('utf-8')
# или 
otherString = unicode(someString, 'utf-8')
```

Если есть возможность, можно объявить строку как содержащую юникод

```
someString = u"string"
```

Comment: если есть не utf-ные символы может вылезти exception, так что лучше использовать 
otherString = unicode(someString, 'utf-8', errors='ignore')
и эти символы будут игнорированы или
otherString = unicode(someString, 'utf-8', errors='replace')
и эти символы будут заменены на похожие

Comment: `.encode()` следует вызывать только для Юникодных строк. `someString = "string"` не создаёт Юникодную строку в Питон 2 (в отсутствии `__future__` `unicode_literals`) и поэтому `someString.encode()` вызов неуместен.  Соответственно `.decode()` следует вызывать на байтах, в которых текст закодирован, чтобы получить Юникодную строчку.

Answer (score 1):

вначале файла надо добавить # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: @cxd Поясните подробней, пожалуйста.

Comment: @pyVyp Похожий вопрос - http://hashcode.ru/questions/293/.

Comment: декларация кодировки исходного кода влияет только на интерпретацию содержимого строковых констант и не имеет никакого отношения к `UnicodeEncodeError`

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы используете Python 2.7? Если да, то функция должна выглядеть так:
    `def __unicode__ fun()`, а не `def __str__ fun()`

У меня такая проблема была.